# How to use Canon remote without the timer?

Tags: canon, remote

I am using a Canon EOS 500D, and just got a digital remote. How can I set the camera to remote control without the timer on it. Because every time I set it to remote control, it always comes with a timer.

Comment: Does the remote have a switch to set a timer interval that might be on? My Canon remote has a slider switch on the back that I can slide to set a 2 second timer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the model.

Canon RC-1 has a slider in front between immediate and 2 sec delay.

Canon RC-5 doesn't have any slider and works only at 2 sec delay.

Canon RC-6 has a slider on the back to accomplish the same job as RC-1.

Check your model leaflet.

Answer (score 2):

With the 500D and the RC-6 (or the discontinued RC-1 that it replaced), you can shoot remotely without the two second delay. You still set the camera to **Self Timer** mode, but you select "no delay" with the slider on the remote. With the RC-5 the only option is to use the remote with a delay.

If you have tried that and are still experiencing a significant delay, try pre-focusing the camera and then switching the lens to Manual focus before using the remote, as the delay is possibly being caused by difficulty achieving focus lock. Since you are not looking through the viewfinder as you normally would to insure the focus point is over a high contrast object, it may well be that the camera is trying to focus on a low contrast object such as a blank wall or clear sky.